# Extending ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

It seems this has been asked many times, in many ways, none of which seem to fit my exact situation.

Here's a line from my _LoginPartial.cshtml file:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

See the part that says User.Identity.GetUserName()?

I want to change it to User.Identity.FirstName or User.Identity.GetFirstName().

I don't want it to say "Hello email address", but rather "Hello Bob"

My thought is that I'm simply wanting to show a new property (or method) on the Identity class. Obviously it must be more than that.

I've added the FirstName property and **it is available** in the AccountController.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

It does not get exposed in the _LoginPartial file. I want it exposed there!

Thank you for your help

Comment: you could always to a db call **where Email is User.Identity.GetUserName();**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though your answer wasn't "exactly" what I wanted, your comments led me to this solution:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using YourModelnameHere.Models
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @{
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); 
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + currentUser.FirstName + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })

            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" }) // I no longer need this ActionLink!!!
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
}
```

And in my IdentityModel.cs file, I added the two properties FirstName and LastName

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can add @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework for a shorter code at the bottom. Good Answer Though!

Comment: oh, thanks for doing the work for me. Diffenetly don't want to show email address to someone walking by. That is half the login.

Comment: This is useful. Added a reference here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/

Comment: I was confused searching all over the web. I've just forgotten to add a `@using MyProj.Models` to access `ApplicationUser`. I've added custom properties already!! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 8):

I've done this by adding the First and Last Name to the claim when the user logs in, and then writing my own extension method.

When the user logs in, add the details you want to the set of claims (`AccountController`):

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add the users primary identity details to the set of claims.
    var pocoForName = GetNameFromSomeWhere();

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, pocoForName));

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

The extension method, which just pulls the details from the set of claims for the user:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static IdentityName GetGivenName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
            return null;

        return (identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
    }

    internal static string FirstOrNull(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        var val = identity.FindFirst(claimType);

        return val == null ? null : val.Value;
    }
}
```

Now in the partial, just call the new extension method to get the details you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetGivenName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

**EDIT: updated to match more closely the original posters version of the SignInAsync() method**

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) 
{ 
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);  

    var identity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
    //add your claim here

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() 
        { 
            IsPersistent = isPersistent 
        }, identity);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Suppose I want to retrieve a value that already exists, such as EmailConfirmed? Is that much different?

Comment: No.  All you need to do is add additional claims in the `SignInAsync` method (pulling the data from wherever you have it stored), and then create corresponding extension method(s) to retrieve them.

Comment: private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));

Comment: Thanks for your responses. This does not work for me - no surprise there - not placing blame at all, but I will keep looking. Have a good evening.

Comment: What is your `SignInAsync` doing?  Is that what you posted above?  If so, you are not setting any claims to the identity.

Comment: "My" SignInAsync is completely different from the one you posted. It calls, what looks to me, like entirely different methods in entirely different fashions.

Comment: Right.  But I have customised mine to suit my purpose, and you will have to do the same.  There may have been changes in the structure of this function between versions of ASPNET Identity.  However, the key point here is that you want to add your additional claim to the identity.

Comment: Can I add an extension method? I think maybe I've not been too clear. Let me try to explain from another angle. There is a property, or method, defined in UserManager as EmailConfirmed. I've tried writing the following extension but no autocomplete in my "user" object. So, I don't know if I wrote it incorrectly, it's not supposed to show in autocomplete
`public static class IdentityExtension
    {
        public static bool EmailConfirmed(this IIdentity user)
        {
            if (user == null)
                return false;
            return user.EmailConfirmed();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

answer updated for Asp .net Core !
Hope this save some time to other users.

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)){

<form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @{

                var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            }

            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @currentUser.FirstName </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

}