# identity 2.0 _LoginPartial First Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My application is MVC5 c#, I have extended the ApplicationUser model to include First and last name, works well.  I am trying to figure out how I can change the loginPartial to display the user actual first name rather than their email address in the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: Which version of asp.net identity?

Comment: See this answer - it was written for version 1, but a lot of the concepts still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394571/extending-asp-net-identity/25395402#25395402

Comment: Thank you Brendan, it did not work because version 2.0 IdentityName is not used, I tried to use ApplicationUser with no luck.  I found this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1957500.aspx; unfortunately it did not work.  I don't get errors but the claim.type is not found, it just returns the original types (Name).

Comment: I meant IdentityUser not Application user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above was my question, unfortunately I could not log with my old account.  Here how I did it:

In the Account Controller / Login I added the following:

```
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            var t = await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("FullName", user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName));
```

Add this class:

```
public static class GenericPrincipalExtensions
    {
    public static string FullName (this IPrincipal user)
        {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

            var claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null)
                {
                foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
                    {
                    if (claim.Type == "FullName")
                        return claim.Value;
                    }
                }
            return "";
            }
        else
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Please see the comments above by Brendan Green, thank you Brendan for the lead.
Changed the _LoginPartial to:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.FullName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {title = "Manage" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly easily by adding the GivenName claim type.  This code was created and tested using the default mvc5 / web application visual studio template that uses asp.net identity 2.

**AccountController.cs**

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                //Add the Full name claim, or any other potential claim information.
                var userClaims = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
                var identity = userClaims.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FullName));

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Note, code like this can get hairy, so you can create an extension method that gets the name and looks cleaner.