# The type or namespace name 'Application User' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# and I'm currently creating an ASP.NET MVC application. I am currently getting the error stated above when attempting to follow the instructions found here: [Extending ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394571/extending-asp-net-identity)

I am trying to get my code to show a user's first name rather than their email address once they are logged in.

Here is my code for _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @{
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + currentUser.FName + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Here is my ApplicationUser class found within IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to have a using directive for your ApplicationUser class in the view, otherwise the class is not visible there

Comment: What would the syntax be for that? I have tried: 
@model ContactManager.Models.ApplicationUser
but that did not work

Comment: You have one "using" already in the view. Syntax is the same, just the namespace and the class are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by putting the below into _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using projectname.Models
```

The other suggestion resulted in a different error message.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `@using ContactManager.Models.ApplicationUser` in you view .